# select function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to upload an excel file to R, the function `read_xlsx` is working fine but for some reason when I add in `select(3:38)` it is bringing up an error message. I have also tried `select(-c(1:2))` which worked yesterday but doesn't seem to want to work today.

```
library(readxl)
library(here)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
data <- read_xlsx(here("Data", "Diss_Survey_Responses.xlsx"))%>%
  select(3:38)
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :  unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’

Comment: You might have loaded another package with function `select`. Try using `dplyr::select` instead of just `select`.

Comment: Restart R session and relaoad the packages and check... at times this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the select code is not working in your case. If this is the case the reason is due to multiple libraries with the same function. In this case specifically, the function `select` exists in the package `dplyr` and `MASS`. If you type in select in your code it's likely going to pull the MASS library, and if your intention is select only certain columns out of a data frame then, then you must write the expanded form of the select `dplyr::select`.

So try the below code:

```r
data <- read_xlsx(here("Data", "Diss_Survey_Responses.xlsx"))%>%
dplyr::select(3:38)
```